# gridster c3 charts auto resizing issue

Tags: angularjs, css, c3.js, gridster

I am facing problem with c3 charts sizing issue with in gridster. Can any one help me how can I make there charts to be properly auto resized according to the gridster box they are in? Please find the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FmS19ZTBln6uEpDUfeOo?p=preview)

I have given size in options :

```
 size: {
        height: 100,
        width: 100
    }
```

If I remove this size property the charts are going out of box. But they are too small in gridster boxes. How can I make these chart to automatically occupy the full height and width of the gridster boxes that they are in?

Comment: Check this out. https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Answer (score 5):

The options you are using:

```
size: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100
}
```

are setting the height and width of the `svg` element to `100px` instead of `100%`
I tried

```
size: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
}
```

Which will successfully set the `width` to `100%` but somehow the `height` will be set to `320px`

So if you add this to your css:

```
.c3 svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

That will solve your sizing issue.

**EDIT**

Just a small change to set up an initial size and some comments added to your controller on the resize - stop event handler, where  you will need to add some resizing of your charts based on the new sizes. [See it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NWBxUo?p=preview)

```
  resizable: {
     enabled: true,
     handles: ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'ne', 'se', 'sw', 'nw'],

     // optional callback fired when resize is started
     start: function(event, $element, widget) {},

     // optional callback fired when item is resized,
     resize: function(event, $element, widget) {}, 

     // optional callback fired when item is finished resizing 
     stop: function(event, $element, widget) {
        // here should update the size according to the widget size
        // widget.sizeX (* 160px) and widget.sizeY (* 160px)
        // and further adjustments
     } 
  },
```

Comment: DDan, Could you please modify my original plunker and make it to work. Because I made these changes to the plunker I have posted in the question but still it  is not working as expected. Please find the plunker updated with your solution still it is not working as expected  http://plnkr.co/edit/5G7bGf2EZ9nKLA8se0oZ?p=preview.   Sorry for my late response as  I was in off whole last week.

Comment: Hi, I won't solve the complete problem but can give some pointers.
http://plnkr.co/edit/NWBxUo?p=preview
I edited the controller. I've set some initial sizes and added a comment on the resize.stop callback. That's where your focus should be. On that event, you are supposed to adjust the sizes of the charts according to the new widget sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem not long ago. What I did is use [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale), but it doesn't work on [firefox](http://caniuse.com/#search=scale).

Basically find the width when loading, and make a new scale when the user changes the screen size (or any other event like resizing your containers).

add this at the bottom of your plunker :

```
<script>

  let width = window.innerWidth;

  window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
      let newWidth = window.innerWidth;
      let ratio = newWidth / width;
      let ctnr = document.getElementById('widget1');

      ctnr.style.transform = "scale(" + ratio + ")";

  });
</script>
```

That will scale widget 1. Of course you might have to play with the numbers a bit to find what works for you.

The widget will stay in place however; thus if you want it to be aligned on the left you can use in your css :

```
transform-origin: 0;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use nvd3 plugin this is same as c3  plugin  also this smoothly works with gridster, Please find the below link

https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/dashboard

Comment: The question to solve the gridster  issue with c3 charts. With nvD3 there is already working sample of it from the author itself http://embed.plnkr.co/jEQMch/

Comment: Looking solution for c3 charts